# Wrapping text around pasted graphic

Tags: graphics, notebooks

I would like to use *Mathematica* to create all my documents for my high school math class.  I cannot, however, find a way to copy and paste a diagram (let's say from Geogebra) and then place it where I want and/or get the text to wrap around it.  Any help?

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica* is a good platform for such tasks because it can't properly export to PDF, doesn't properly handle bibliographies, takes  undue effort to make references to equations and figures, etc. I always tell people to use [LyX](http://www.lyx.org) instead. There, you can use the `wrapfig` inset to solve your issue. And unlike other $\LaTeX$ frontends, `LyX` supports direct pasting of graphics into the document.

Comment: There is a "SideCaptionArray" cell style used in the presentation templates that could help on this. But there is very little information about it.

Comment: It's a shame this isn't possible. With a little more work on page layout, *Mathematica* would be *killer* for writing and typesetting technical documents of all kinds, especially homework assignment handouts, exams, problem solutions, etc. in the mathematical sciences.